# Laravel dynamic connections to different databases at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm building a Laravel Stock Management Application that allows each subsriber (user) to have a `stock` in a separate database.

All the users' databases have the same design originating from the same Laravel migrations.

And I have a `master_database`, which contains a `stock` table as follows :

```
id  database_name
1   stock_1
2   stock_2
```

- The `master_database` is the default database, and its credentials are  in the .env file)

The users will be able to login to the app by submitting a form with 3 fields:

```
- database_name
- email
- password
```

I do the following when the user wants to connect to `stock_1` database for example :

1 - I check if the `stock_1` database exists in the `stock` table (in the `master_database`).

2 - I connect to `stock_1` database by changing the database config dynamically by providing the `database_name` to this method :

```
public static function connect($db)
{
    // get default connection
    $connections = \Config::get('database.connections');
    $newConnection = $connections[\Config::get('database.default')];
    $newConnection['database'] = $db;
    $newConnection['username'] = 'root';
    $newConnection['password'] = 'root';

    \Config::set('database.connections.' . $newConnection['database'], $newConnection);
    \Config::set('database.default', $newConnection['database']);
}
```

3 - I check in the `users` table in this database if the `email` & `password` entered are correct, and I log in the user.

So my questions are:

- Does this dynamic database configuration affect the whole project ?
- What if there are many users trying to connect to different databases at the same time? Is this going to work or they'll all share the same last modification to the config?
- Is there a better way to do this while keeping each stock in a separate database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this dynamic database configuration affect the whole project ?

Yes it is, as long as you have called this `connect` method you defined every time the request came in.

> What if there are many users trying to connect to different databases at the same time? Is this going to work or they'll all share the same last modification to the config?

Every time a user make a request, the initial config would be the one from .env until you called your `connect` method. So yeah, it won't break even there are many users connect to your server (as long as they are in different requests).

> Is there a better way to do this while keeping each stock in a separate database?

I think you can put your connect method in a middleware, so that you can connect to the desired database whenever an authenticated user make a request.

Comment: I see, but the problem is when `user_1` is connected to `stock_1`, so in this case the database configuration is set to `stock_1`. But right after that `user_2` connects to the app on its own `stock_2` databaase. What will happen to the configuration ? and will the `user_1` automatically connect to `stock_2` even if it's not his database ?

Comment: When you set the config, it would only affect the current request. So nope, it won't affect user_1.

Comment: Oh, I didn't imagine that it worked like that. Can you please recommend for me any resources that would help me understand how the config is working especially for cases like this, because there is nothing mentionned about this in the docs.

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/lifecycle). A fresh laravel instance is bootstrapped and instantiated every time a request is made. Every request is standalone and every changes the request has made won't take effect unless there are somewhere to store it (database, cache).  There are no way for two php requests to communicate with each other (in my understanding). I have used this approach to change config too.

Comment: I have edited the comment above. Besides that, to test out the approach, I think you can make two request, one of them with `sleep`. The first request change the config > sleep > respond database name, the second request directly change config without sleeping, and see what they both respond.