# how can i use laravel multi-database?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I want to know about the laravel multiple databases. is it possible to use a default database which use only user login and after login separate group by group and every group use independent database. such as `'db'` is the default database it's only for the all user login.

**Example**: Now `'John'` is login using default database `'db'`. John is the member of group1 after login john use `'db1'` where stored `John's` all type of data. Other side Now `'Alex'` login using default database `'db'`. Alex is the member of group2 after login Alex use `'db2'` where stored `Alex's` all type of data. After login default db connection no need so i want to replace `'bd' to 'db1' or 'db' to 'db2'`. Please provide code for laravel

Comment: you can see here https://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections

Comment: Sounds like tenancy. There are packages for this.

Answer (score 1):

Define a separate database connection in `config/database.php`.

```
'mysql' => [ // default
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    ...
],
'db1' => [ // another 
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST_ONE', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT_ONE', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_ONE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_ONE', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_ONE', ''),
    ...
]
```

**Note** that you have to define respective config in your `.env`.

Then when you want to use `db1` connection it, use `Config::set('database.default', 'db1')`. However, it only works when you have known amount of database connections(that you can define in `config/database.php`), if you have unknown amount of databases, then you should change the config directly instead of the name of the connection only.

Example:

```
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', 'db1')
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.username', 'admin');
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.password', 'secret');
```

You can see [my another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55393321/laravel-dynamic-connections-to-different-databases-at-the-same-time/55394256#55394256) to know how does it work underhood.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I presume you are building a system that is connecting to various existing databases possibly from different applications.

You can define as many DB connections as you want in your `config/database.php`

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
],

'mysql2' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST_2', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT_2', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_2', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_2', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_2', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
],
...
```

You would however also need a way to specify for each user which other external DB from which their details are going to be fetched from, for instance a column `db_name` on the `users` table.

At the point of fetching the data of say `'Alex'` User model, you can do something like

```
$user = User::find(1); //if Alex has user_id 1 and where $user->db_name is 'mysql2' as is in the config/database.php file

$userDetails = DB::connection($user->db_name)->where('username',$user->name)->where('other_details','some details')->get();
```

Make sure to specify this in your `.env` too, to match what's defined in `config/database.php`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

DB_HOST_2=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_2=3306
DB_DATABASE_2=db2_name_here
DB_USERNAME_2=db2_username_here
DB_PASSWORD_2=db2_password_here

...
```